# How to cache generated UIImageViews in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I am doing a project that loading the contacts from local device. Then, base on the contact Id I generated a UIImageView for each contact. And the problem is I saved UIImageView in each contact instance as a property, so it will take a lot of memory.
I know I should use caching. But I don't know how to use caching techniques in Objc.
Please help me and give me some links to learn about it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) to solve it, it will help you cache imagedata.
You can install with CocoaPods.

**Installation**

```
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0'
```

**Import headers in your source files**

```
#import <SDWebImage/SDWebImage.h>
```

**Usage**

```
[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]];
```